# List Item to Discussion Board make title "ID_.000"

Tags: 2010, workflow, discussion-board

I have a workflow setup to create a Discussion Item on a Discussion Board when a new Item is made in another list. It works as expected, except that it sets the title of the discussion item to "ID_.000" where ID is the ID number of the discussion Item. How can I make the title be set to what I have the subject set too?

Edit: I just confirmed for myself that it wasn't an error in my workflow causing this. I just created a workflow in another list that when ran, creates a new discussion item with the subject "Test Discussion." However that to when it creates a new discussion item it labels the subject correctly but gives the item the title "ID_.000" where ID is the ID of the new discussion item.

Edit 2: I just noticed when filtering the Title field it shows what I want in the drop down. How do I make it display that in the field?

[image: Screen Shot]

Edit 3: I should also note that when a discussion is posted directly on the db (not using a workflow) the title is normal.